# How to add Excel File name in all rows exists in that excel in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have more than 100 excel files.My job is to merge to all the excel files into one excel. I did easily by writing the C# program for merging excels. Now I need to Identify the records as per the excel file name.I mean I need to add the actual Excel file name to the new columns for all rows exists.

For Example:
I have excel Dom.xls having 2 rows in that excel.

```
   Name   SSN   Address
    1      0923  1 winter st
    2      0924  2 winter st
```

Now I need the excel should create new column named"Excel File Name"

and should write the file name like beow

```
   Name   SSN   Address         Excel File Name
    1      0923  1 winter st     dom.xls
    2      0924  2 winter st     dom.xls
```

How Do I achieve this.

Either I need this requirement before merging all the excels or after merging the excels.

Below code I used to merge all excels.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MergeExcel.DoMerge(new string[]
       {             
          @"C:\Users\dom\Desktop\Reim Account\032 - dom_AMESBURY.xlsx",
          @"C:\Users\dom\Desktop\Reim Account\128 - dom_BRAINTREE.xlsx",
          @"C:\Users\dom\Desktop\Reim Account\960 - dom_RETIREMENT.xlsx"....etc
       },
          @"D:\MyExcel\dom.xlsx", "V", 2);
    }
}

public class MergeExcel
{
    Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

    //initialize the object of saved target 
    Excel.Workbook bookDest = null;
    Excel.Worksheet sheetDest = null;

    //initialize the object of read data
    Excel.Workbook bookSource = null;
    Excel.Worksheet sheetSource = null;
    string[] _sourceFiles = null;
    string _destFile = string.Empty;
    string _columnEnd = string.Empty;
    int _headerRowCount = 0;
    int _currentRowCount = 0;
    public MergeExcel(string[] sourceFiles, string destFile, string columnEnd, int headerRowCount)
    {

        //Use class Missing case to indicate the missing value. e.g. when you call the method that has default parameter value
        bookDest = (Excel.WorkbookClass)app.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
        sheetDest = bookDest.Worksheets.Add(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value) as Excel.Worksheet;
        sheetDest.Name = "Data";
        _sourceFiles = sourceFiles;
        _destFile = destFile;
        _columnEnd = columnEnd;
        _headerRowCount = headerRowCount;
    }

    //open worksheet
    void OpenBook(string fileName)
    {
        bookSource = app.Workbooks._Open(fileName, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        sheetSource = bookSource.Worksheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;
    }

    //close worksheet
    void CloseBook()
    {
        bookSource.Close(false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    }

    //copy table header
    void CopyHeader()
    {
        Excel.Range range = sheetSource.get_Range("A1", _columnEnd + _headerRowCount.ToString());
        range.Copy(sheetDest.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value));
        _currentRowCount += _headerRowCount;
    }

    //copy data
    void CopyData()
    {
        int sheetRowCount = sheetSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        Excel.Range range = sheetSource.get_Range(string.Format("A{0}", _headerRowCount), _columnEnd + sheetRowCount.ToString());
        range.Copy(sheetDest.get_Range(string.Format("A{0}", _currentRowCount), Missing.Value));
        _currentRowCount += range.Rows.Count;
    }

    //save the result
    void Save()
    {
        bookDest.Saved = true;
        bookDest.SaveCopyAs(_destFile);
    }

    //exit the process
    void Quit()
    {
        app.Quit();
    }
    void DoMerge()
    {

        //declare variate bool to judge if copy table header
        bool b = false;
        foreach (string strFile in _sourceFiles)
        {
            OpenBook(strFile);
            if (b == false)
            {
                CopyHeader();
                b = true;
            }
            CopyData();
            CloseBook();
        }
        Save();
        Quit();
    }
    /// merge table
    /// source file
    /// object file
    /// the sign of the last column
    /// the number of rows of table header
    public static void DoMerge(string[] sourceFiles, string destFile, string columnEnd, int headerRowCount)
    {
        new MergeExcel(sourceFiles, destFile, columnEnd, headerRowCount).DoMerge();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it Feasible?

Comment: Yes it's definitely feasible.  I would use the Nuget package ClosedXml as the easiest route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this in `CopyData`. Send the filename to CopyData `void CopyData(string strFile)`. Then after `range.Copy` add the following lines.

```
Excel.Range range_name = sheetDest.get_Range(string.Format("E{0}", _currentRowCount), string.Format("E{0}", _currentRowCount + sheetRowCount));
range_name.Value = strFile;
```

This will add the filename to column `E`. Maybe some tweaking is necessary since I'm not that familiar with Excel Interop.